# Running a privelaged script from a post-receive git hook on my server

Tags: ssh, permissions, git

Say I have the following workflow to deploy a new version of my webapp. It's a small app so all the build + deploy work is done on the same server (`example.co`)

- A user executes `git push` which pushes new code up to my server (`example.co`)
- The server has a bare git repository which receives the changes. It kicks off a [`post-receive` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)
- The post-receive hook runs a build script which builds a new docker container and starts it up

The git repository is managed by a dedicated `git` user on my server. This is so that any developer can add a git remote ssh url like `ssh://git@example.co:/some/path.git` and push up to it using SSH

The build and deploy work is done by a `deploy` user since this requires `sudo` permission.

How do I have my `git` user kick off a script as the `deploy` user? Should the git user even have any way to do that, because anyone could ssh into the machine under the `git` user right?

Is there a better way to segment these permissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You grant permission to the `git` user to run the script you want it to run as the `deploy` user:

```
git ALL=(deploy) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/some-script ""
```

> Should the git user even have any way to do that, because anyone could ssh into the machine under the git user right?

Well, for starters, hopefully not *anyone* can log into the machine, only people who have a legitimate need to access that account.  Secondly, SSH as the `git` user should be triggering a forced command, so the people logging in shouldn't be able to trigger the deploy script arbitrarily.  Finally, the script being invoked should be written in such a way that it can't do anything more damaging than "redpeloy known-safe code which already got deployed before", so there really shouldn't be any downside to someone being able to trigger the script repeatedly, other than perhaps resource exhaustion.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. It seems like editing the sudoers file with the above line will *allow* my git user *permission* to run that file as `deploy`, but I still need to configure git itself to run it with elevated permissions when calling the hook. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: You'd edit the hook script that git calls to run whatever other script you want with `sudo -u deploy` at the front.